# Make "coverage report" only display files from current directory?

Tags: python, django, code-coverage

Consider the following example:

```
> django-admin startproject testproject
> coverage run ./manage.py test        
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
> coverage report 2>&1 | head -n 20
Name                                                                                                                  Stmts   Miss  Cover
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__                                                            9      0   100%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/__init__                                                       2      0   100%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config                                                        84     23    73%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry                                                     186     75    60%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__                                                      87     29    67%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/global_settings                                              136      0   100%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/locale/__init__                                                2      0   100%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__                                                 48     34    29%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/__init__                                                    0      0   100%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__                                             10      0   100%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/actions                                              36     26    28%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps                                                 13      0   100%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks                                              401    212    47%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/decorators                                           12     11     8%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/exceptions                                            5      0   100%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters                                             197    132    33%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers                                             225    161    28%
/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/migrations/0001_initial                               7      0   100%
```

How can I make "coverage report" only report files from the current directory, i.e. project files?

Comment: Checkout http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html. Likely fixed by providing the `source` value under `[run]`.

Comment: I copy-paste your example to debian and got just files of the project listed - so maybe it depends on version/configuration (also I had to cd into the testproject directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `--source=.`, or the equivalent in your .coveragerc file.